# Reading in all videos in folder for optical flow

Tags: python, opticalflow

I want to read multiple avi videos into my optical flow python code.

This is what I'm currently using for a single video.

cap = cv.VideoCapture("029f_hap_4.8_sta_1_2.9for4sc50.avi")

Can you advise me how to create a loop to read in all the videos so that I can run the code on all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: is your videos in a folder?

Comment: Yes all the videos are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
import os
import cv2 as cv
dirpath = '/path/to/your/video/dir'
os.chdir(dirpath)

# assuming inside the folder, all the files are video file type
video_list = os.listdir('.')

for video in video_list:
    cap = cv.VideoCapture('./' + video)
```

Comment: This won't work, as listdir returns nested folders, not just files

Comment: not when you are inside the folder itself. I changed working dir to where he keeps his video files.

Comment: What is he has nested folders there too?

Comment: I already noted that I assume inside the folder, all file types are video file.

Comment: All file types are avi in the folder

Comment: if you have folders containing videos , then the codes need a little more modification but in your case, I think this code is enough :). @JessJordan

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile
some_path = "enter your path here"

folder_contents = os.listdir(".")
for item in folder_contents:
    if os.path.isfile(item):
        do_something(item)
```